# To access the other applications package name in our application

Tags: android, caching, package

I want to use the package name of other application through my application is it possible to do so.I want to clear the cache of other application.Instead of /data/data can i use other applications package name ?

```
File[] cacheFiles = new File("/data/data").listFiles();
for(int i = 0; i < cacheFiles.length; i++){
    cacheFiles[i].delete();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your device is rooted you will not be able to access data of other applications.

Further deleting /data/data deletes dbs, caches, sharedprefereces and most private data of all apps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is mean by rooted

Comment: I meant you need root [access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29)

Comment: how to get the root access is there any permission required

Comment: you will have to load custom firmware. It depends on phone model. search on google for root access [your phone name]

Comment: ok,Thank you, Is there any other way to clear the other application cache

Comment: nope. other application cache is protected. Only OS can do it if you have not rooted

Comment: Can we delete the whole directory ?

Comment: no. you cant touch any folder in \data\data unless it is yours